# Scrollable Tabs at fixed position in android

Tags: android

I'm making custom camera app and I need to create a camera buttons like picture, video and time laps button as similar to instagram camera. By default its show picture button but I want to change it when someone swipe finger on it.

Here is image of instagram camera

[image: Instagram camera]

As you can see in image when user swipe on white ball it moved to next **BOOMERANG** and so on and back and forth. 
Or if user click on any tab it set in the middle right above the arrow and white ball also convert in some other image. 
I want similar functionality But I don't know how to achieve this because I'm new in android. Can you please let me know what I need to read for this.
Thanks.